# Heap space problem - number sequence iterative loop

Tags: java, heap-memory

I have an assignment to create a number sequence following starting numbers {0, 1, 2} where additional numbers are calculated using the formula: n = (n - 1) + (n - 3) resulting in the sequence.

I'm having issues with that my loop is running out of heap space. Does anyone have any suggestion on how to resolve this?

I need to be able to calcualte up to n = 1,500,000,000

```
public long calculate(long n) {
    // If n is one of known values return that value
    if(n<=1){
        return 0;
    }
    if(n==2){
        return 1;
    }
    if (n==3){
        return 2;
    }

    // initate array to calculate
    ArrayList<Long> seq = new ArrayList<Long>();
    int x = 0;
    long y = 0;
    seq.add(y);
    seq.add(y);
    seq.add(y+1);
    seq.add(y+2);

    // for loop until reached requested number
    for (int i = 4; i<=n; i++){
        seq.add(seq.get(i-1)+seq.get(i-3)) ;
    }
    for (int i =0; i<n; i++){
        x++;
    }
    return seq.get(x);
}
```

Comment: the question is not clear, what are you trying to do again?

Comment: as you need at most a backlog of 4(index-3,index-2,index-1,newindex) : 4 variables should do (plus a runner - also consider making the runner long). also there are simpler ways to set x=n than a for loop.